# Android Studio, error, in navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am trying to only make a navigation drawer. I am getting these errors -

```
$        Error:(7, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_menu_camera').
Error:(11, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_menu_gallery').
Error:(15, 19) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow').
Error:(23, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_menu_share').
Error:(27, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_menu_send').
```

Trying to follow this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju837bQOBfg

Here is my global.xml file that has the error

```
$<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_first_layout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="First Layout"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_second_layout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Second Layout"/>

<item android:id="@+id/nav_third_layout"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
    android:title="Third Layout"/>
    </group>

    <item> android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>


        </item>
    </menu>
        <!--</menu>-->
   <!-- </item>-->

    <!--<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"-->
        <!--android:title="@string/action_settings"-->
        <!--android:orderInCategory="100"-->
        <!--app:showAsAction="never" />-->
```

[Here is the source code from the video](http://robinsonprogramming.com/tuts/download.php?page=downloads_android_studio_$_NavigationDrawer.zip)

I can also upload my source code. I am a beginner in android studio and my only goal right now is to learn how to make the navigation drawer. Any alternate help, link to easier tutorial or pointers to where I am going wrong would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Check if that resources exists in the drawable folder

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't import the drawables themselves. From the link you posted about the source code from the video, navigate to /NavigationDrawer/app/src/main/res/drawable-v21/ , here is where all the drawables are, just copy everything in here and paste it under your drawable folder.